# How to debug MacOS/iOS calendars discovery process

Tags: ios, calendar, ical, xml, caldav

I'm putting together a Caldav server and both iOS 14 and MacOS Catalina seem to be ignoring the XML responses and then both continuing to try different URLs until giving up.

I've posted details here:
[stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67563890/caldav-discovery-from-ios-to-caldav-server)

How can I figure out what is going on?